# What is the difference between Array.Copy and Array.CopyTo?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there any difference between `Array.Copy` and `CopyTo`? Are they just overloaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at it carefully. `Copy` is a static method whereas `CopyTo` is an instance method.

Answer (score 9):

Same functionality, different calling conventions. `Copy` is a static method, while `CopyTo` isn't.

```
Array.Copy(arraySrc, arrayDest, arraySrc.length);
arraySrc.CopyTo(arrayDest, startingIndex);
```

Comment: Popester: you have given a wrong syntax.  syntax for copy is Array.Copy(srcarray,destarray,srcarray.length);                          and also for copyto mehod:  srcarray.CopyTo(destarray, destarray_index);                                                    more details refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

Comment: What Gmathipriya says is right: it should be: arraySrc.CopyTo(arrayDest, arrayDest.StartIndex);

Answer (score 7):

But they are not only convention-wise different; there is a key functional difference.

Here is an excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx):

> This method (`Array.CopyTo`) supports the `System.Collections.ICollection` interface. If implementing `System.Collections.ICollection` is not explicitly required, use `Copy` to avoid an extra indirection.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx  and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx,
We will see that:

### Array.CopyTo

- able to copy multidimensional arrays.
- easier to specify range to be copied.
- static method.

### CopyTo

- have better performance. (as [husayt answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667856/1941881))
- instance method.

And there are something I am not sure that, the remarks of `Array.CopyTo` said:

> This method is equivalent to the standard C/C++ function `memmove`, not `memcpy`.

Which `CopyTo` do not have such description.
It is true that it is not easy to copy part of an array to it self using `CopyTo` without parameters to control range. Still, you could use `ArraySegment` or `array.Skip(offset).Take(length)` to achieve it.
And in my test, there is no problem to do so.

Comment: It's a mistake that got me wild goose chasing. Please somebody edit the answer, I tried twice at different times and couldn't. It's `Array.Copy` instead of `Array.CopyTo`. `CopyTo` is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, I don't know if there is anything different between the two other than the CopyTo method will copy **all** elements of the array and Copy will allow you to specify a range of elements to copy